# Sorting in a HierarchicalDataTemplate not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview

I had my WPF/VB Treeview working just fine then I tried to add live sorting and everythings gone south.  Now nothing shows in the TreeView control when I run my app.  Here's what I did:

Added this converter:

```
Public Class CollectionViewSorter
Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim collection As System.Collections.IList = TryCast(value, System.Collections.IList)
    Dim view As New ListCollectionView(collection)
    Dim sort As New SortDescription(parameter.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(sort)
    Return view
End Function
Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return Nothing
End Function
End Class
```

In the Window.Resources I have this:

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Key="cvs"
    IsLiveSortingRequested="True">
</CollectionViewSource>
<local:CollectionViewSorter x:Key="Sorter" />
```

and this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildNodes, Source={StaticResource cvs}, Converter={StaticResource Sorter}, ConverterParameter=Name}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

and, finally, I define the CollectionViewSource.Source in code-behind as:

```
Dim cvs As CollectionViewSource = CType(TryFindResource("cvs"), CollectionViewSource)
cvs.Source = Nodes
```

What is wrong with the above?

EDIT:
Per my comment below, I removed the guts of the converter so it is now this:

```
Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim collection As IList = TryCast(value, IList)
    Return collection
End Function
```

and the TreeView is still empty.  Thus, my conclusion is that the converter is the source of the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Nodes` is a property.

Bind your source in XAML like this :

```
<CollectionViewSource
            x:Key="cvs"
            Source="{Binding Nodes}"
            IsLiveSortingRequested="True"/>
```

Remove these 2 lines :

```
Dim cvs As CollectionViewSource = CType(TryFindResource("cvs"), CollectionViewSource)
cvs.Source = Nodes
```

***Converter in c#***

```
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        ICollectionView view = (ICollectionView) value ; 
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(parameter.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        return view;
    }
```

I checked, your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks for looking this over, @AnjumSKhan.  Yes, Nodes is just an ObserveableCollection of Node, which is a class with properties ID, ParentID and Name.  I know the collection is being filled properly.  Sadly, your suggestions made no difference; the TreeView is still empty.

Comment: By the way, I think the problem is in the converter but that is just a hunch because I don't know what is wrong with it nor do I have any idea how to change it.

Comment: Still gives a blank TreeView.  I've also tried other variations of the converter.  For example, I tried adding a DirectCast on the view you created back into an ObservableCollection but that didn't help either.

Comment: You are doing something else. I post answer after checking it from my side.

Comment: I just tried putting trace and debug statements in the converter and nothing was output.  Now I think the problem is that the sorter is simply not being called at all.  But then I've been wrong before.